# how to manage client side state in asp.net mvc3 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net we can save post back data using view state i.e for client side state management,i.e default for asp.net web forms.is view state is default for asp.net mvc ?if not how can we save the post back data and  is there any replacement of view state in mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC does not uses ViewState. it don't have server side controls to retain the state.

but you can use ViewBag, ViewData to store the values and use it in your views.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var someList= new List<string>
    {
        "C#, 
        "Java", 
        "PHP"
    };

    ViewData["Languages"] = someList;

    return View();
}
```

in your view

```
<ul>
@foreach (var lang in (List<string>)ViewData["Languages"])
{
    <li>
        @lang 
    </li>
}
</ul>
```